# What is the delta of a portfolio invested in different stocks?

Tags: portfolio, delta

I understand that if I have a portfolio invested in stock **A** and options on stock **A**, the delta of my portfolio is going to be the weighted sum of the delta of the stock (=1) and of the option.

Now if I have a portfolio invested in stocks **A** and **B** and in options on these stocks, does it make sense to compute a global delta of the portfolio as the weighted sum of all the deltas? Or do we have to compute a delta that relates to **A** and a delta that relates to **B**?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with this number ("portfolio delta")?

Comment: Nothing, I just want to know if it still makes sense to talk about the delta of a portfolio when there are different stocks and options on these stocks in it.

Comment: What do you mean by "sense"? Sense in what way?

Comment: I think your question doesn't make sense as it stands. A better question would be about the delta of an option with different underlyings (e.g. a basket option).

Comment: I believe you did not understand my question. If I have a portfolio with *Z* shares of **A**, *W* shares of **B**, *X* options on stock **A** and *Y* options on stock **B**, it does not make sense to talk about the *delta of the portfolio* right ? It makes sense to talk about the *delta of the portfolio related to **A** or related to **B** right ?

Comment: No, it makes sense to talk about the delta of the option on stock A and the delta of the option on stock B. It only makes sense to talk about some aggregate delta when you have a well defined derivative structure on stocks A and B.

Comment: So when people ask *"What is the delta of your portfolio?"* it does not make sense?

Comment: No, not really. And who are those "people"? Please give a source.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71314/discussion-between-arthurim-and-vonjd).

Answer (score 4):

Strictly speaking, you cannot aggregate (i.e. sum)
deltas. However, equity traders often provide their net
exposure in currency units, which is a useful number. The same reasoning is
possible with equity options: You can compute the
'delta equivalent position', i.e. delta times number of
contracts (times multiplier) for each stock. Taking
the delta equivalent position times the stock price
gives you a hypothetical exposure in currency units,
and adding these exposures up gives you a total
exposure in currency units.

Answer (score 2):

You can consider a multivariable delta if your security $V$ depends on two stocks $A$ and $B$: the gradient of $V$ is 
$$\nabla V=\left\langle \frac{\partial V}{\partial A}, \frac{\partial V}{\partial B}\right\rangle.$$
If you want a single number, there are indeed [Greeks for multi-asset options](http://www.investment-and-finance.net/derivatives/tutorials/greeks-for-multi-asset-options.html).

Comment: I think this doesn't answer the question because the OP wanted to have a delta _of an portfolio_ and not on a security _which depends on_ a portfolio (see my comments above). Additionally: do you have a source for your definition of a multivariable delta? Also: could you give an example how to use that definition in practice?

Comment: @vonjd One thing you could do in practice is use the well-known fact that the gradient points in the direction of greatest increase. So you can find out what relative changes in $A$ and $B$ will lead to greatest increase in $V$ (like, an increase of 5 dollars in $A$ for each 1 dollar increase in $B$).

Comment: @vonjd I should have mentioned that in my answer $V$ represents the total value of all stocks and options held. So $\partial V/\partial A$ is, by linearity of partial derivatives, a "weighted" sum of the deltas of the various assets.

Comment: A problem here is that the movements of different stocks are not independent (orthogonal).

Answer (score 0):

Since Delta is an options construct only, your question needs to be restated. I am assuming your are trying to find the risk of your portfolio against a market correlation.
You can use Beta to combine your portfolio as long as you are trying to correlate your portfolio against SPY.